# an item is hidden in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

please run the following code in chrome window and you will see that "Menu 1" is disappeared .. any help .. why this happens ??

```html
<div class="page-container">
 
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    
     <button class="visible-xs navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">First Name</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row row-offcanvas-left">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-xs-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      
       <ul class="nav nav-stacked navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add margin to `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`. Because bootstrap's `.navbar-fixed-top` class has position:fixed and its overrides top of the menu. Or you can just remove class `.navbar-fixed-top`